# Python OpenCV code question: I can not open video file

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:
When I press SPACE it starts saving video,and when I press SPACE again or press ESC, it stops saving video. The code worked, but I cannot open video file which is saved.

```
capture=cv.VideoCapture(0,cv.CAP_DSHOW)     
width=capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height=capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps=capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
fourcc=cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')   
output=cv.VideoWriter('images/output.avi',fourcc,fps,(int(width),int(height)))  #
save=False
while capture.isOpened():   
    ret, frame = capture.read()     
    if ret==True:
        cv.imshow('Camera',frame)  
    key=cv.waitKey(1)  
    # output.write(frame)
    if key==32:   
        save= (~save)  
    if save==True:     
        output.write(frame)    
    if key==27:  
        break   
capture.release()  
output.release()    
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

What's the problem for this code?